# Mysql fulltext boolean search - sort by relevance and one more field

Tags: mysql

So basically I have two tables. First table called 'photos' looks like this:

```
id title
1  Some text here
2  Another text here
```

and the second table called 'likes' looks like this

```
id photos_id user_id
1  1         10
2  1         11
3  2         12
```

photos_id corresponds to id from 'photos' table

I am using the following query to do fulltext boolean search and then sort by relevance

```
SELECT *, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('text' in boolean mode)
AS score FROM photos
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('text' in boolean mode) order by score desc;
```

Sorting by relevance is working well but now I want to sort also by total number of likes when the relevance is equal ... something like "**order by score, total_likes desc**". Any help?

Comment: So, what's the problem? You can order by two fields, exactly as you've shown.

Comment: Your suggested solution will work fine except that results will seldom have equal relevance.

Comment: @sashkello yes but i need to count how many likes each photo has first, and i am unable to do this in the same statement

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes in the example above if someone searches 'text here' they are both going to have same relevance, then i need to sort by total likes too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `Left Join` for it and check [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aad70a/1) here.

```
SELECT
  p.*,
       MATCH (title) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score ,
       COUNT(li.id) AS total_likes 
FROM photos p
  LEFT JOIN likes li
    ON p.id = li.photo_id
     WHERE  MATCH (p.title) AGAINST ('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    GROUP BY 
      li.photo_id

ORDER BY 
      score , total_likes DESC
```

Comment: using this website for the first time, is this what you wanted? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08cfd

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30832/discussion-between-deval-shah-and-user1768337)

Comment: I would suggest a small change in this, it should be **score DESC, total_likes DESC**