# How to sort the results from full text index search based on relevance

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i have problems in sorting the results of my sql query based on the relevance.

Here is my query at present.

```
SELECT author FROM search WHERE MATCH(author,title,series) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Can anyone tell me the solution as to how to sort the results based on relevance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql fulltext boolean search - sort by relevance and one more field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812501/mysql-fulltext-boolean-search-sort-by-relevance-and-one-more-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the match as part of your query, and it comes back as a "score". You can then sort on that. IE:

```
SELECT 
  author,
  MATCH(author,title,series) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE) as score
FROM 
  search 
WHERE 
  MATCH(author,title,series) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
  score
```

UPDATE: Here is a weighted example

```
SELECT 
  author,
  (
   (MATCH(author) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE) * 20) +
   (MATCH(title) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE) * 10) +
   (MATCH(series) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE) * 5)) as score
FROM 
  search 
WHERE 
  MATCH(author,title,series) AGAINST('Anna Selby' in BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
  score
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. But still the result is not coming as desired. A name with Tedd Selby has a score higher than that of Anna Selby. Any idea how? I have used the exact same query that you gave. I'm also getting a sort of warning..

"Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Comment: It is hard to say why without looking at your data, but since you are matching against 3 columns and using a Boolean search, your search is probably finding more matches (ie on Selby) in the 3 columns combined for Tedd then for Anna. You can weight your score if you want, giving more points to author or title. I added an example above. Check the [full docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) for more info

Comment: Hey thanks a lote for your help but i'm getting an error again.

Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list 

This is the error its showing.

Comment: How did you define your FULLTEXT? You may need to add keys for the columns individually to score them individually. ALTER TABLE search ADD FULLTEXT(author), add fulltext(title), add fulltext(series), add fulltext(author,title,series);

Comment: No, the FULLTEXT index will only work on MyISAM tables

Comment: Hey sorry to bug you again. I am having a bit of a trouble in the display results. Everything is working fine. Except for one case. if my author is A Selby and i search for A Selby then the results having Anna Selby  as author are displayed first and then a selby. both are provided the same score. Is there any way by which i can make sure that A selby is displayed first and then Anna Selby

Comment: You can add an additional sort to your query. IE ORDER BY
  score, author, title etc.